# Update Button Via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a button that adds a vote to a post whenever a user clicks it. The posts are being rendered in the index view, but when the button is clicked for a user to add a vote, I get a 500 error in the console, but on refresh the vote has been added. Below is the code I'm using:

Pages Controller where the posts are being rendered:

```
  @posts = current_user.feed.paginate(:per_page => 6, page: params[:page])
```

Favorites Controller:

```
  def create  
   current_user.favorites.create(:post_id => params[:post_id])  
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to post }
    format.js { render :toggle }
   end    
  end
```

Toggle.js.erb (favorites/toggle.js.erb)

```
 $("#favorite").html("<%= escape_javascript render('shared/fave_form') %>");
```

Favorite Form

```
<% if current_user.favorites.find_by_post_id(post.id) %>   

<% else %>
  <%= form_for favorite, :html => { :method => :delete }, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Unlike" %>
  <% end %>         
<% end %>
```

Comment: It might behoove you to add the form and the javascript as well. Since it seems to be an issue with the javascript and form.

Comment: I'll go ahead and add that in an edit.

Comment: you are showing us the `create` method but using `destroy` `:method => :delete` will route to `favorites#destroy`